# LED Flat panel wiring — Type NM/Romex or Lamp Cord

Tags: electrical, wiring, led

I purchased several LED flat panel fixtures that came without wiring instructions.

I’m using suspension cable kits to hang the lamps from an open basement ceiling with fiberglass insulation and TJI-type joists.

The lamps have Junction Boxes (pictured) with what look like type NM (romex) inputs — to the LED driver — and tiny, maybe 18-20 gauge lines to the LEDs themselves.

The fixtures draw a rated 40 watts.  I have a junction box in the ceiling currently with a bare bulb fixture.

Is it necessary **or required by NEC** to use  type NM-B/Romex to wire these fixtures?  It doesn’t seem very useful to use solid NM rather than stranded lamp cord, since I’ve seen simple lamp cord  provide power safely to 150-watt floor lamp bulbs all my life.

[image: Junction box on LED fixture photo]

[image: bare bulb in junction box photo]

Comment: What's the issue with using NM here? Handling?

Comment: Only cost and ease.  I’d at least like to confirm positions of the lights before cutting my roll of Romex to length and really “committing” to the fixtures’ final positions.

Comment: Would you be open to other wiring methods?

Comment: Sure — the only ways I can think of are NM/Romex and Lamp Cord, with either being connected via wire nuts and held by cable staples once everything is working.

Comment: Do you want to be able to dim them in the future?  Also, is leaving a bit of extra cable up in the ceiling for future positioning an issue for you?

Comment: I was thinking about it.  I know it requires 0-10v dimmer switch at the wall and an extra wire run which would be easily done. The label (photo) says do NOT connect the LED +/- and Dimmer, while the manufacturer’s website [has a diagram](https://www.lightup.com/media/downloads/786/Lumegen_Panel_Light_Instructions.pdf) showing that being done.  So that’s pretty confusing.  Maybe I don’t understand what they mean by those words about the “Dimmer” in the photo.

Comment: No issue with extra cable— I’ve pre hung the first two using aircraft cable style hangers and am planning to leave the excess cable cooled and zip tied above the fixtures already.

Comment: The weird label instructions mean "don't short the LED outputs to the dim inputs" basically, AFAICT

Comment: Oh, that would make a lot more sense.  That might let out some of the “magic smoke.” 

Comment: Do you have access to an electrical supply house that can order things in for you?

Comment: Are you running cables all the way from the switch box, or are you starting at some intermediate point?

Comment: Also, is your concern about getting the luminaire (fixture) into the right place *now*, or being able to move it *later*?

Comment: Sure, can use an electrical supply house.  Already have six of the fixtures though.

Comment: Currently have a wall switch that runs Romex to a single bare bulb and outlet box nailed to the ceiling.    This is for a 16x16 storage room so one bulb is insufficient to use it as a hobby space.  The ceiling joists and wall are unfinished so it would be easy to run a dimming wire alongside the existing Romex.

Comment: I was going to run whatever type of wire from the existing junction box to the new fixtures.

Comment: I know I can get the NM/Romex to the new fixture locations, but having prehung now two of them to the ceiling, using aircraft cable type hangers, (1) they bend under their own weight so I suspect the Romex will make it even harder to hang flat and (2) I’m not sure about light evenness (lumens) and dispersion so I may want to reposition them a couple of times.  I used [the visual3D tool](https://www.visual-3d.com/tools/interior/) to check my lumens and number of fixtures, but there are ducts across the ceiling that I have to work around and couldn’t model.

Comment: It's super unclear to me how you are mounting these to the ceiling.  Are they fixed hard to the ceiling using screws?  Or are they hanging from cables or chains and able to flex and move?   Also [the UL listing hologram appears to be valid](http://productspec.ul.com/document.php?id=IFAO.E489648).

Comment: I’m using aircraft cable type hangers.  [This one from Amazon, specifically.](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B06XKTK39P/) It has small L-brackets that can be screwed to the top of the Fixture, attached to a very long cable... and a piece (really a nut, or a threaded socket) that screws to the ceiling. The cable is pushed into the socket, there’s a spring-tensioner that is used to pull up the fixture and then it’s at final height.  I’ve attached two of these fixtures to the bottom of my TJI-type I-joists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I gather that you're hanging the lights from cables or chains, and as such, it's possible for them to move or swing.  **As such, you must use *cordage* for the connection from light to fixed ceiling box**.

Cordage is - well, it's the type of electrical wiring you've been handling all your life.  Almost every appliance has a cord.  It's designed to flex.  It also costs a little more. It's not allowed as permanent wiring, except for a certain few exceptions.

Use of cordage to *luminaires* in open spaces is explicitly allowed by NEC 400.7 (now 400.10), and I make full use of it.  Further, nothing says you can't make them *cord-and-plug-connected*. They make cover plates that take receptacles, for 4" (across the corners) octagon boxes.

[image]

Don't let price tempt you into using a 2-prong cord.  The cable/chain hangers are NOT grounds. For 3-prong cords-with-plug, my favorite is [Target's $5 8' extension cord](https://www.target.com/p/outdoor-extension-cord-black-8-woods/-/A-12874804), lop off the socket end and you're all set. It's stiff, though; McMaster-Carr has more flexible ones cheap, but the shipping!  If you're hardwiring both ends, your local electrical supply will have a variety of cordage, use at least 16 AWG.

However, cordage is not allowed above a drop ceiling or in any kind of plenum space: NEC 400.7 (now 400.12).  In that case you need to use one of the Chapter 3 wiring methods, typically a flexible metal conduit or prefabricated wire whip.

Lastly, ballast disconnects. Code requires any *hardwired* luminaire to connect via disconnect plugs. LEDs might be exempt because they're not *technically* fluorescents.  However, the principle is the same: the power supply/ballast is likely to fail at some point, and you need a way to de-energize with certainty.  Since you have to make a connection betweeen house wiring and driver *anyway*, make it through one of these.   These cost less than $1 each.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Another great source of flexible cordage w/ plug is IEC cables -- since every computer and monitor needs one, they're even more of a cheap commodity.  https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=5279

Comment: At 40w or ..33 amps I would the smallest cord I could find if plugging them in but if hard wiring then it gets a bit more complicated since the entire assembly is not ul listed.

Comment: Great info here. I believe my units in the picture above have an equivalent quick-disconnect (pushbutton to release the wiring.). Now I know why.   **Do I maintain UL rating and code-compliance** if I hardwire all four or six fixtures in the room, using IEC type cordage, with plug-ends cut off, from the fixture’s junction box, all the way to a wire-nut in the ceiling junction box?   I assume each fixture needs its own “home run” to a junction box.  It sounds like from your answer I do, not sure from @EdBeal ‘s comment as to whether this wiring would be considered “permanent” or not.

Comment: If you're snipping off both socket and plug (or even if you're retaining the plug) the labeling on the side of the cord is what decides whether it's legal. It must be a legal type for cordage, e.g. SJOOW, SJTW, etc.  I wouldn't trust cheapie mail-order IEC cables unless I actually read the numbers off the side of the cord.  But yes, you go in a strain relief or cable clamp into the junction box, and wirenut to in-wall wiring there.

Comment: Hey, is there a limit to how long the cordage can be – how far away the outlet box is?  If the cordage needs to be held in place with a staple is that considered “permanent” and/or a problem?

Comment: @whiskeychief as a matter of fact, there is no limit.  I have a 40' one.  I would use 2 hooks faced opposite directions not a staple. Cordage isn't made to be crimped like Romex. (Well that isn't either).